# I have too many div's what else can I use?

Tags: html, css

I've been doing dev on this online form submissions site and using HTML/CSS to align the fields and what not. I was doing fine until i needed to put little boxes around each section because I would have too many div's and would close each other when I don't want them to. So my question is, is there a way to explicitly tell each closing `</div>` to close certain div class' or should I just use another tag in general.

HTML:

```
<div class="print_content">
              <div class="generalinfo">
                <h4>User Information</h4>
                <hr/>
              </div>  
              <!--form starts-->
                <form>
                    <div class="half">
                      <legend><b style="color:red",>*</b>
                        <label for="name">Name</label><legend>
                        <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
                    </div>
                    <!-- added div class clear to have a half class in 1 row -->
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                       <div class="half">
                         <label for="email">Email</label>
                          <input type="text" id="email" name="email">
                        </div>
                    <div class="half">
                        <label for="zip">Zip / Postal code</label>
                        <input type="text" id="zip" name="zip">
                    </div>
                      <div class="half">
                          <label for="abc" class="alignleft">abc</label>
                          <span class="left-text">abcabc</span>
                      </div>
                    <div class="half">
                        <label for="country">Country</label>
                        <select id="country" name="country"><option></option></select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="full">
                        <label for="message">Message</label>
                        <textarea id="message" name="message"></textarea>
                    </div>

                    <div class="full">
                        <label for="zip">Zip / Postal code</label>
                        <input type="text" id="zip" name="zip">
                    </div>
                    <div class="half">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="copy" name="copy">
                        <label for="copy">Send me a copy</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="half">
                      <legend><b style="color:red",>*</b>
                        <label for="name">Name</label><legend>
                        <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="half">
                                <div class="nocolor">
                                    <a href="www.google.com">google</a>
                                </div>
                    </div>
              </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: You should be using `ul` and `li` tags here

Comment: `<p>` tags would also be a fit.

Comment: I don't understand your problem: `I would have too many div's and would close each other when I don't want them to`? If you have `div`s closing the wrong div, then your markup is wrong (mismatching opening and closing tags) and you should correct it. Which element you use does not matter at all.

Comment: As it stands, your code is malformed - at the end you close three divs, but it should be div - form - div. Give http://validator.w3.org/ a try - it will tell you, what is wrong with your HTML. In case of your posted markup, it finds 4 errors.

Answer (score 0):

I think "< ul >" with some "< li >" would be great here. 
Just do it like this:

```
<ul>
 <li class="half">
  <input ...
  <label ...
 </li>
</ul>
```

Further information http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html

HTML often gives you more than one (or 10) possibilities to achieve something. Generally I like your approach to use a very basic element (like a div) if you don't know a more specific one. 
If you're feeling again like you're using too much divs and that there might be another solution, just search for sites which have a similar solution than your product implemented. With "F12" (most browsers) you can explore what they've used.